# How to disable automatically insert linebreak in need?

Tags: latex

I have install a plugin named `latex for wordpress`, which use mathjax to render the latex mathematical symbols.

An matrix example

> $$\mathbf{P} = \left[ \begin{matrix} x\ y\ \end{matrix}
>   \right],\mathbf{P'} = \left[ \begin{matrix} x\ y\ \end{matrix}
>   \right],\mathbf{T} = \left[ \begin{matrix} t_{x}\ t_{y}\
>   \end{matrix} \right] $$

The problem is I could not break the statement into multiple lines when the statement become too long in a single line. Because wordpress would automatically insert `<br>` to the equation.

So I need to disable automatically generation of `<br>` in and only in this circumstances.

Could I do this with some extra tags?

Comment: You might get more help from the [plugin's support forum](http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/latex)

Comment: Is this a shortcode by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, you're using a `latex` shortcode, the following should do what you've asked for:

```
function leave_latex_alone($content) {
    $new_content = '';
    $pattern_full = '{(\[latex\].*?\[/latex\])}is';
    $pattern_contents = '{\[latex\](.*?)\[/latex\]}is';
    $pieces = preg_split($pattern_full, $content, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

    foreach ($pieces as $piece)
        if (preg_match($pattern_contents, $piece, $matches)) $new_content .= $matches[1];
        else $new_content .= wptexturize(wpautop($piece));

    return $new_content;
}

remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');
remove_filter('the_content', 'wptexturize');

add_filter('the_content', 'leave_latex_alone', 99);
```

This is an adapted version of some [code found here](http://www.adammershon.com/stop-wordpress-from-removing-br-and-p-tags/). However, I did not test the code.

Comment: This does not work, the latex statement would not render any more.